# is T, near the identity, invertible?

Tags: functional-analysis, linear-transformations

If $X$ is a Banach space and $T:X\to X$ is a linear continuous transformation such that $\|I-T\|<1$ then T is invertible.

Comment: I don't see a question in the body of your post.  Please ask your question in the body of your post, and include your thoughts on it, what you tried, where you're stuck, etc.

Comment: Hi, I don’t know how to prove that T is invertible.

Comment: I tried to prove that $/|T(x)/| > C|x|$